# concatenate array to array with specific positions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

i have a array of array like below.

```
  const array1 = [[8,1,2,3,1],[3,1,1,1],[4,2,1]];
```

what i need to do is append six empty values " " in-between last two values for each element.

[image]

Expected output:

```
[ [ 8, 1, 2, '', '', '', '', '', '', 3, 1 ],
  [ 3, 1 '', '', '', '', '', '' , 1, 1,],
  [ 4, '', '', '', '', '', '', 2, 1 ] ]
```

What i tried:

i know how to append this to end of each element like below. can I modify my code with adding positioning?
What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
 const array1 = [[8,1,2,3,1],[3,1,1,1],[4,2,1]];
const appendArray = new Array(6).fill('');
const map1 = array1.map(x => x.concat(appendArray));
console.log(map1)
```

Comment: looks like you want to `.splice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array [.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) could be one way

```js
const array1 = [[8,1,2,3,1],[3,1,1,1],[4,2,1]];
const map1 = array1.map(x => {
  const copy = [...x];
  copy.splice(-2, 0, ...Array(6).fill(''))
  return copy;
})
console.log(map1)
```

Although ... personally I hate splice ... this is better because it's a one liner :p

```js
const array1 = [[8,1,2,3,1],[3,1,1,1],[4,2,1]];
const map1 = array1.map(x => [...x.slice(0, -2), ...Array(6).fill(''), ...x.slice(-2)])
console.log(map1)
```

Comment: Very minor, but since `Array(6).fill('')` is static, it can be moved out of loop. Nice implementation though

Comment: ahh, yes, of course - but then it's not a one liner in the second code :p - though, the reason why it can be moved out of the loop is nothing to do with it being static, it's because it's being copied using `...`

Comment: yes One line code is much better. [starting position ,in-between and finally end part]. Looks very simple and organized

Comment: @Rajesh if moved ` ...Array(6).fill('')` to out of map.it will show the different output right? like this element `[ 4, [ '', '', '', '', '', '' ], 2, 1 ]`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Just curious - What is the reason you need to copy the array in the first example? Why can't you use just x?

Comment: @adam not if you insert it with the spread operator

Comment: @E-g - I hate splice :p I think that would mutate the original array element of array1 - (confirmed, it does, which perhaps the OP does not want to do)

Comment: @Adam Not `...Array(6).fill('')`. Just declaration part `const filler = Array(6).fill('')` and then `copy.splice(-2, 0, ...filler)`. Point is, you are creating 2 new arrays in every iteration and also filling. That can be reduced to 1 new array in every iteration and 1 fill for all. But its just a minor optimisation

Comment: @JaromandaX *but then it's not a one liner in the second code*, I leave this responsibility to webpack. But I accept its an opinionated comment, hence added *very minor* at the start

Comment: @JaromandaX Got it :)

Comment: Good discussion Forks!!! Learned a lot .

Comment: @Adam .... Forks? :p

Comment: haha. cant edit now.... :p

Answer (score 1):

What `concat` does is just adds the empty value array to the end of array `x`. What you need is to separate the beginnings and the ends. Than return the array with spreded values like so

```js
const array1 = [[8,1,2,3,1],[3,1,1,1],[4,2,1]];
const appendArray = new Array(6).fill('');
const map1 = array1.map(x => {
  const beginning = x.slice(0, x.length - 2);
  const end = x.slice(-2);
  return [...beginning, ...appendArray, ...end]
});
console.log(map1)
```

Comment: Nicely explained!!!